# Unexpected indentation error in Python, but only when combining two otherwise working statements

Tags: python, indentation

The following two code pieces, when placed in the [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-eval-print_loop) by themselves, work properly:

1)

```
with open('/shared/errorStatsByDowAndHour.tsv','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        phs.append([twodec(l.strip()) for l in line.split('\t')])
```

2. 

```
for p in phs:
    print p

['1-00', '34550', 38493.75, '42154', 2745.61]
['1-01', '24087', 32319.5, '42742', 6985.69]
['1-02', '13853', 20238.25, '27358', 5407.19]
['1-03', '14686', 20409.0, '27999', 4798.54]
..
```

However, when combined as follows:

```
with open('/shared/errorStatsByDowAndHour.tsv','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        phs.append([twodec(l.strip()) for l in line.split('\t')])
for p in phs:
    print p
```

The following error is generated:

```
>>> with open('/shared/errorStatsByDowAndHour.tsv','r') as f:
...     for line in f:
...             phs.append([twodec(l.strip()) for l in line.split('\t')])
... for p in phs:
  File "<stdin>", line 4
    for p in phs:
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>     print p
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print p
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

What is the explanation?

Comment: The REPL needs an additional empty line to end a suite of commands.

Comment: @mgilson The given 5 lines of code are not a "suite of commands"? Why would lines 1 to 3 need an empty line before lines 4 and 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you drop back to top-level after an indented block in the interactive interpreter, you need to input a blank line to indicate that Python can now execute the block.

If your goal is to be able to copy/paste code from a script to the interactive interpreter and have it run, you can do the following:

```
exec r'''
[copy/paste your code here]
'''
```

Make sure to inspect the code for docstrings and other stuff that could mess this up first, though. You may be able to switch the quote type to make it work.

Comment: Similarly to mgilson I am not following this comment. I have entered a blank line after the five lines of code. If that is not precisely what you mean here pls clarify.

Comment: @javadba: You drop back to top level after the first 3 lines. You need a blank line at that point.

Comment: Ok. So then code has to be mangled a bit to run within the interpreter?  Is there a workaround for this? Specifically is there a repl option to override this behavior?

Comment: I do have a script. I am testing portions of it in the interpreter. Are you contending that is not a reasonable use case?

Comment: @javadba: Yeah, I remembered the use case after posting that. I've edited a workaround into the answer.

Comment: The exec syntax seems to work, nice suggestion. pls consider to upvote the question.